# Rendered animation doesn't play

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, video, gpu

When I render an animation in the normal ffmpeg h264 MP4 format, when it's done rendering, it doesn't play. And it's fustrating to wait till it finishes rendering only for it not play. Please what can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>CTRL+F11</kbd> in the main Blender screen (this is **not** the render result)